# Can't get JS to work on modal image gallery

Tags: javascript, image, modal-dialog, image-gallery

I've tried half a dozen different ways of making this work, but none of them do and I'm starting to get really frustrated. I know this is definitely a newbie thing but I don't care.

I'm trying to make an art gallery with modal images, and I've followed [this tutorial](https://owlcation.com/stem/javascript_gallery) to the letter, literally only switching out the actual image files/paths, but it won't work. The images show up fine and the styling is fine, they transform when I hover over them, but upon actually clicking them, nothing happens. I've moved the JS code from its own linked file to the body of the main html file and that changed nothing. I've tried several different methods, including the 'official' W3Schools tutorial, and while that successfully netted me a single modal image, it refuses to work for a gallery. I tried the lightbox thing on the same site and it didn't work either. I want to stick with a similar format to the one linked above, but honestly at this point I'm about ready to throw my laptop in the river.

Please, someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code so far, including the css (which has been working just fine) and the js that refuses to do Anything:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0px 60px 0px;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.gallery_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.gallery_item img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  margin-top: -1px;
  animation: zoom 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0);}
  to {transform:scale(1);}
}

.modal img {
  width: 50%;
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.closeBtn {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

.closeBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

  </head>
  
  <body>


<div class="main">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 chal revolution.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 chal space fall.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 chal.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 cute bobbydane.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 dane lip ring.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="/pics/2016_11 esther amaden.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery_item img");
let imgIndex;
let imgSrc;
//get images src onclick
images.forEach((img, i) => {
  img.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    imgSrc = e.target.src;
    console.log(imgSrc);
    //run modal function
    imgModal(imgSrc);
    //index of the next image
    imgIndex = i;
  });
});

//creating the modal
let imgModal = (src) => {
  const modal = document.createElement("div");
  modal.setAttribute("class", "modal");
  //add the modal to the main section or the parent element
  document.querySelector(".main").append(modal);
  //adding image to modal
  const newImage = document.createElement("img");
  newImage.setAttribute("src", src);
  modal.append(newImage);
  //creating the close button
  const closeBtn = document.createElement("i");
  closeBtn.setAttribute("class", "closeBtn");
  //close function
  closeBtn.onclick = () => {
    modal.remove();
  };
  //next and previous buttons
  const nextBtn = document.createElement("i");
  nextBtn.setAttribute("class", "angle-right nextBtn");
  //chenge the src of current image to the src of next image
  nextBtn.onclick = () => {
    newImage.setAttribute("src",, nextImg());
  };
  const prevBtn = document.createElement("i");
  prevBtn.setAttribute("class", "angle-left prevBtn");
  //change the src of current image to the src of previous image
  prevBtn.onclick = () => {
    newImage.setAttribute("src", prevImg());
  };
modal.append(newImage, closeBtn, nextBtn, prevBtn);
};
//next image function
let nextImg = () => {
  imgIndex++;
  //check if it is the last image
  if (imgIndex >= images.length) {
    imgIndex = 0
  }
  //return src of the new image
  return images[imgIndex].src;
};
//previous image function 
let prevImg = () => {
  imgIndex--;
  console.log(imgIndex);
  //check if it is the first image
  if (imgIndex < 0) {
    imgIndex = images.length - 1;
  }
  //return src of previous image
  return images[imgIndex].src
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check my answer? I ran your code successfully after I fix the issue. :)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QiVPCxm.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had typo in this code

```
newImage.setAttribute("src",, nextImg());
```

change it like this

```
newImage.setAttribute("src", nextImg());
```

Comment: I. Cannot _believe._ That's what was wrong. I must've made the same or similar typos in other versions. Now though, I'm having the problem where the next/previous buttons are itty bitty and on the same side of the images, but I can figure that out on my own as well as fiddle with other stuff. Thank you _so much._